# 'Window' object has no attribute 'setGeometry'

Tags: python, qt

I am trying to display the ADC value read from a grove(connected to raspberry pi) to Pyqt5 based GUI application. I am trying to get adc value from `Pi_hat_adc()` class and send to `Window()` class where I am displaying the ADC value in a `QLineEdit` widget. While running the code I am getting the attribute error:

```
'Window' object has no attribute 'setGeometry'
```

My python version is 3.8. Help me resolve the issue.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from grove.i2c import Bus

ADC_DEFAULT_IIC_ADDR = 0X04

ADC_CHAN_NUM = 8

REG_RAW_DATA_START = 0X10
REG_VOL_START = 0X20
REG_RTO_START = 0X30

REG_SET_ADDR = 0XC0


class Pi_hat_adc():
    def __init__(self,bus_num=1,addr=ADC_DEFAULT_IIC_ADDR,parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.bus=Bus(bus_num)
        self.addr=addr
             
    def get_nchan_adc_raw_data(self,n):
        data=self.bus.read_i2c_block_data(self.addr,REG_RAW_DATA_START+n,2)
        val =data[1]<<8|data[0]
        return val

class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pi_hat_adc = Pi_hat_adc(parent=self)
        self.setGeometry(200,200,400,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("ADC grove example")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #25ffa4")
        self.label = QLabel("ADC grove example",self)
        self.label.move(100,10)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        line_edit = QLineEdit("",self)
        line_edit.setGeometry(5,80,100,40)
        line_edit.setStyleSheet("background-color:White")
        line_edit1 = QLineEdit("",self)
        line_edit1.setGeometry(5,140,100,40)
        line_edit1.setStyleSheet("background-color:White")
        line_edit2 = QLineEdit("",self)
        line_edit2.setGeometry(5,200,100,40)
        line_edit2.setStyleSheet("background-color:White")
        while True:
            rawdata0 = self.pi_hat_adc.get_nchan_adc_raw_data(0)
            line_edit.setText(int(rawdata0))
            rawdata1 = self.pi_hat_adc.get_nchan_adc_raw_data(1)
            line_edit1.setText(int(rawdata1))
            rawdata2 = self.pi_hat_adc.get_nchan_adc_raw_data(2)
            line_edit2.setText(int(rawdata2))
            time.sleep(4)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Programming question, not related to U&L per se

Answer (score 0):

Your `Window` class has no `setGeometry` method so `self.setGeometry(200,200,400,300)` has to fail. You probably wanted  the `Window` class to inherit from `QMainWindow` or some other Qt widget so your code should probably look similar to this:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
    
        self.pi_hat_adc = Pi_hat_adc(parent=self)
        self.setGeometry(200,200,400,300)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance while i am editing the code according to your reply. But in the while loop it shows the error TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'. so i commented the lineedit section of the code and rerun the app but in this time it compiled without any error but the window is not popping up.

Comment: You are passing integer to `setText` but it expects string: `setText(int(rawdata0))`

Comment: Also the window will never show because you have an infinite loop with sleep in the  `__init__` function so the `Window` class is never initialized and the `window.show()` line is never executed.

Comment: I changed the code something like this setText(str(rawdata0)) now iam getting the value in the lineedit widget but i need to read it continously how to read it.